# How to make the body of a table occupy less width than the head of the table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically What I'm trying to accomplish is this kind of table

https://cloudup.com/cj0w8auGPPT

I'd like the head of the table to occupy 100% and the rest of the table to occupy let's say 95%

I will appreciate any approach,

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The head and body seem to be occupying the same width

Comment: AFAIK it's impossible to set different width to `thead` and `tbody`, you can create an illusion by using `colspan` or simply adding empty cells.

Comment: It is not entirely impossible - there is a workaround that does not involve adding empty cells or colspan, please see my answer below. The advantage of the nested-table method below is that it allows for a locked header - that way, when the body of the table overflows, you can place a scrollbar only on the body and keep displaying the header.

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the illusion of the head being 100% and the rest being 95% by adding an empty column to the left and right of your actual table.

Otherwise, tagging your table elements and then adjusting their respective widths in `CSS` using `width: 100%;` and `width: 95%;` would do the same according with a little more effort. **Note:** the head would need to be a separate table from the rest of the table.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use nested tables, with the first table containing the header and the second the rows of data. 
Here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/why9n859/
It may require some modifications to align it perfectly but it should work for this purpose.

HTML:

```
<table id="t1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="left">#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <div>
    <table id="t2" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 2.75%;">

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Some</td>
            <td>Stu</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
thead { background-color: #09d; color: white; }
tbody {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
th { padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; }
td { padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; }
#left { padding-left: 40px; }
#right { padding-right: 40px; }
```

Another approach is to create a single table for the data with an empty header row. Above the table, create a  to hold the actual column headers. You can use Bootstrap to create a row with columns. Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid so be sure to make the size of all column headers add up to 12. Then set the background color of the custom header row to whatever you want and make the table width less than 100% of the view. Here is a decent tutorial on the CSS "width" property: http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Bootstrap 2.3.2 syntax:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Stu Nicholls has a good demo of nested tables and what you can do with them - for instance the header row can be locked while the body scrolls.
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be just add an empty extra left and right column and specify the desired offset width.

http://jsfiddle.net/133L67Lx/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>02/08/15</td>
            <td>Vivian Voppnrueden</td>
            <td>savion_beahan@goldnerolson.org</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>02/08/15</td>
            <td>Hattie Bashirian</td>
            <td>nash_weigand@torphy.name</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;    
}

thead tr{
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    color: #FFF;
}

tbody td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 5px;
}

td,
th{
    text-align: left;
}

th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2){
  text-align: center;  
   padding-left: 0;
}

th:last-child,
td:last-child{
    padding-left: 0;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child,
td:last-child,
th:last-child{
    width: 5%;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```